# Android: infinite ListView loading items at wrong time

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to implement an infinite `ListView`, it has 10 elements loaded first, when I scroll to the bottom of these 10 elements, it should load another 10. This is the code I've written till now:

```
    private class ResultListScrollListener implements OnScrollListener{

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (mResultListView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= mResultListView.getCount()-1 && mResultListView.getLastVisiblePosition()<count-1) {
                        page_num++; 
                    //count is final variable=60 so that scrolling stops at 60.
                        Log.i("onScrollStateChanged", "last visible: "+ mResultListView.getLastVisiblePosition() + " Page num: " + page_num);
                        new LoadItemsAsyncTask().execute();
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) { 
            }

        }
```

It does load more elements, but it loads at wrong time, instead of loading when last visible position is 9, 19, 29 .... etc , it loads erratically, like twice at 9, then skips 19 then thrice at 29. How can I fix this? Here is my LogCat output so you can see when the `onScrollStateChanged` has been called:

```
07-09 12:16:06.197: I/onScrollStateChanged(27014): last visible: 9 Page num: 1
07-09 12:16:06.648: I/onScrollStateChanged(27014): last visible: 9 Page num: 2
07-09 12:16:11.122: D/dalvikvm(27014): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1069K, 26% free 3477K/4643K, paused 11ms+4ms
07-09 12:16:24.946: I/onScrollStateChanged(27014): last visible: 29 Page num: 3
07-09 12:16:25.376: I/onScrollStateChanged(27014): last visible: 29 Page num: 4
07-09 12:16:26.527: I/onScrollStateChanged(27014): last visible: 29 Page num: 5
```

**EDIT**

I got it to behave properly by keeping a track of the previous last visible position and loading items only if the previous is NOT equal to the current. So now I have

```
 @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (mResultListView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= mResultListView.getCount()-1 && mResultListView.getLastVisiblePosition()<count-1
              && mResultListView.getLastVisiblePosition()!=last_visible) { //added this condition
                        page_num++;
                        Log.i("onScrollStateChanged", "last visible: "+ mResultListView.getLastVisiblePosition() + " Page num: " + page_num);
                        last_visible=mResultListView.getLastVisiblePosition();
                        new LoadItemsAsyncTask().execute();
                    }
                }

        }
```

Now I get proper output like:

```
07-09 12:33:26.152: I/onScrollStateChanged(27734): last visible: 9 Page num: 1
07-09 12:33:29.735: D/dalvikvm(27734): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1092K, 26% free 3455K/4643K, paused 10ms+7ms
07-09 12:33:33.969: I/onScrollStateChanged(27734): last visible: 19 Page num: 2
07-09 12:33:43.409: I/onScrollStateChanged(27734): last visible: 29 Page num: 3
07-09 12:33:49.014: I/onScrollStateChanged(27734): last visible: 39 Page num: 4
07-09 12:33:53.979: I/onScrollStateChanged(27734): last visible: 49 Page num: 5
```

But I am unable to understand why it did not work without the dit. Any explanations?

Comment: see those two gists https://gist.github.com/pskink/b21c932f405740011144 and https://gist.github.com/pskink/9ab862cdd0d6b0281ab4

Answer (score 0):

If u want an easy solution go with chris banes pull to refresh libraries

1.> https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

2.> https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

All the listviews in this library have an onLastItemVisibleListener where you can put your code

You can also check wether the list is already refreshing by isRefreshing() to stop the list from loading again.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to implement it myself, and now I got it working anyhow (see my edit) but I want to know what is wrong with my original code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation which works enough well

```
    list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        // is the number of list items (counted from the end) that should, if visible, trigger the loading process.
        // If you set threshold to 0, for instance, the user has to scroll to the very end of the list in order to load more items.
        int treshhold = 0;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if(isLastPageEmpty){
                    return;
                }

                if (list.getLastVisiblePosition() >= list.getCount() - 1 - treshhold) {
                    page++;

                    if(itemsArray != null) {
                        lastVisibleListPosition = itemsArray.size();
                    }

                    GetItemsAsync async = new GetItemsAsync();
                    async.execute();

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        }
    });


private class GetItemsAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Result> {

    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // send request for new items
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            if (result.status.equalsIgnoreCase("fail")) {
                // show error 
            } else {
                if(result.items.size() == 0){
                    // no more items
                    isLastPageEmpty = true;
                    return;
                }

                if (itemsArray == null) {
                    itemsArray = result.items;
                } else {
                    itemsArray.addAll(result.items);
                }

                adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), itemsArray);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

                // scroll list to previous position
                if(lastVisibleListPosition > 0){
                    list.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                                    list.setSelection(lastVisibleListPosition - 1);                                                     list.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to implement it myself, and now I got it working anyhow (see my edit) but I want to know what is wrong with my original code?

Comment: debug your application more and check results. hard to say without full application source code. If it's working now, what's the problem? :)

Comment: There is no problem now :P Just wondering why the error occurs in the original code, it seems that the behaviour of onScrollStateChanged is slightly different than what I thought, so wanted clarification for possible future implementations

Comment: "mResultListView.getLastVisiblePosition()<count-1" this condition should be removed, I think

Comment: Without that condition, even if I have a max of 60 items in 6 pages, it will try to load the 7th page , 8th page etc

Comment: in real world you can't know about total items count, just server knows

Comment: count is actually retrieved from server

Comment: @Kartik_Koro use a standard  SimpleCursorAdapter with a PagedCursor that reads pages on demand,  see my comment above